# CSS selector works, jquery selector doesn't (IE only issue)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Please note that the following is an IE only issue (as usual...)

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<label for="foo">
  <span>some foo text</span>
</label>
```

I have a CSS rule that is working perfectly:

```
#foo + label > span{  
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I then have a CSS selector which match the same CSS selector which is not returning anything:

```
var textVal = $("#foo + label > span").text();
```

But for some reason if I use the following line, it is going to return the correct value:

```
var textVal = $("#foo + label").html() or .text()
```

I really want to select the label's span, because I want to change the text of it and don't want to append a new span everytime.

Thank you,

EDIT:

Interesting, if I do the following it works...

```
var label = $("#foo + label");
var textVal = $(">span",label).text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var textVal = $("label[for='foo'] span").text();
```

Comment: yes this and my edit works to. But I still don't get why my first selector didn't work. Because the first part of the selector $("#foo + label") was working just fine

Answer (score 1):

This is working in IE8 for me.  Perhaps its' because you didn't close the " on `checked="checked` ?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mEAYr/

Comment: this is just stackoverflow not showing it for some reason. Oh and btw, im using IE7